# How do I save states to a file and keep the file safe?

Tags: java

I'm trying to create save states for my game, not so much for where your game was left but something simple like score boards. The format would be something like this:

```
Wins: 5
Losses: 10
GamesPlayed: 15
```

I need to be able to access the file, and depending on whether the player won/lost it will append +1 to the value in the file.

What would be the best way to go about this? I've heard of a bunch of different ways to save data, for example XML, but aren't those overkill for the size of my data?

Also, I do want to keep this file `safe` from the users being able to go into the files and change the data. Would I have to do some sort of encryption? And, if the user removes the file and replaces it with an empty one can't they technically reset their values?

Comment: Just use plain `Serialization`.

Comment: Yep! If they can get their hands on the file, they will technically reset their scoreboard history. But as @LuiggiMendoza mentioned, `Serialization` would do the trick for all your other requirements.

Comment: I suggest using a properties file with encrypted values.

Comment: @R.J : Can't the user open the serialized file and update the int value there?

Comment: @Manish nope, since its serialized the user could open and see garbage characters there.

Comment: @Manish - That is `Serialization`. The object persisted won't be in human readable format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use plain serialization/deserialization for this. In order to serialize/deserialize a class, it must implement the `Serializable` interface. Here's a example to start with:

```
public class Score implements Serializable {
    private int wins;
    private int loses;
    private int gamesPlayed;
    //constructor, getter and setters...
}

public class ScoreDataHandler {

    private static final String fileName = "score.dat";
    public void saveScore(Score score) {
        ObjectOutputStreamout = null;
        try {
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            out.writeObject(score);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle your exceptions...
        } finally {
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public Score loadScore() {
        ObjectInputStreamin = null;
        Score score = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            score = (Score)in.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //handle your exceptions...
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException ioe) {
                }
            }
        }
        return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, you're great help. I do have one question though, is serializing saving the score and making it unreadable and deserializing the opposite?

Comment: @DanielContreras de nada :)